# DB query error. Code: 42601 Message: syntax_error Cause: ERROR: syntax error at or near "<"

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I get this error:
DB query error. Code: 42601 Message: syntax_error Cause: ERROR: syntax error at or near "<",
when I try to execute my query

I am trying to get the 'organizations' that contain the most 'shows' with a tag from the 'selected_tags'.

```java
    @SqlQuery("SELECT DISTINCT organisation.id, organisation.name, organisation.type, " +
            "                organisation.logo_asset_id,organisation.address, organisation.status, count(s) " +
            "FROM organisation " +
            "    LEFT JOIN channel c on organisation.id = c.organisation_id " +
            "    LEFT JOIN show s on c.id = s.channel_id " +
            "    WHERE (<selected_tags>) && s.tags " +
            "    GROUP BY organisation.id, organisation.name, organisation.type, " +
            "             organisation.logo_asset_id,organisation.address, organisation.status " +
            "    ORDER BY count(s) DESC " +
            "    LIMIT (:limit) OFFSET (:offset);")
    List<Organisation> findByTags(@BindIn("selected_tags") List<String> tags, @Bind("limit") int limit, @Bind("offset") int offset);
```

Comment: `WHERE (<selected_tags>)` - what do you mean?  Is this a column?

Comment: This is jsql. I am trying to bind tags parameter to <selected_tags> and compare it to s.tags

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to bind a list with JDBI but I think your SQL statement is incorrect.

A correct one should look like below:

```sql
...
WHERE s.tags IN (<selected_tags>)
...
```